# How to fix "Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled" exception while connecting to PostgreSQL

Tags: corda

We are in a phase where we need to replace H2 database by Postgresql database for our application. We followed the guidelines given in the below URLs.

URL: [How can the Corda node be extended to work with databases other than H2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232016/how-can-the-corda-node-be-extended-to-work-with-databases-other-than-h2)

URL: [Replacing h2 database with some other relational database in Corda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098008/replacing-h2-database-with-some-other-relational-database-in-corda?rq=1)

However, the node that is to be connected to Postgresql fails to run and an exception "Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled" is thrown.

We set the autocommit off in Postgresql by running command 
"\set autocommit off;" in PSQL tool, but still the above exception is thrown by the node.

We are using V1 of Corda. 
Should we migrate to higher version - V2, V3?

Comment: Auto-commit is a connection (session) specific property. Setting it to off in the psql commandline client has no effect on other connections. JDBC does not allow calls to commit in auto-commit, but a connection defaults to auto-commit. So either you need to disable auto-commit (using `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` or not call commit in your code.

Comment: Is there a global setting?

Comment: No, although sometimes connection pools or JDBC drivers have a connection property to disable it by default. For example HikariCP (which seems to be used by Corda), has a property `autoCommit` which can be set to false to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the related stack question (below link), it is answered that postgresql is supported by corda versions 2 and above.

([Using PostgreSQL instead of H2 as the Corda node's database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419854/using-postgresql-instead-of-h2-as-the-corda-nodes-database))

The auto-commit issue found in corda version 1 may not exist in corda versions 2 and above.